# Module importing multiple times with django + celery

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have a module which is expensive to import (it involves downloading a ~20MB index file), which is used by a celery worker. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to have the module imported only once, and only by the celery worker.

Version 1 `tasks.py` file:

```
import expensive_module

@shared_task
def f():
    expensive_module.do_stuff()
```

When I organize the file this way the expensive module is imported both by the web server and the celery instance, which is what I'd expect since the `tasks` module is imported in both and they're difference processes.

Version 2 `tasks.py` file:

```
@shared_task:
def f():
    import expensive_module
    expensive_module.do_stuff()
```

In this version the web server never imports the module (which is good), but the module gets re-imported by the celery worker every time `f.delay()` is called. This is what really confuses me. In this scenario, why is the module re-imported every time this function is run by the celery worker? How can I re-organize this code to have only the celery worker import the expensive module, and have the module imported only once?

As a follow-on, less important question, in Version 1 of the `tasks.py` file, why does the web instance import the expensive module twice? Both times it's imported form `urls.py` when django runs `self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)`.

Comment: Thing is celery tasks are ideally idempotent meaning they don't have any state and always deliver the same output when called with the same parameters. - You are somewhat introducing state, thus doing this with celery might become difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Make a duplicate tasks.py file for webserver which has empty tasks and no unneeded imports.

For celery use version 1 where you import only once instead of every time you call that task.

Been there and it works.